# случайные координаты Google Maps в России

Tags: google-maps-api

Задача следующая:
Сделать при каждом обновлении страницы фоном рандомные фото улиц с google street view.
С фотокарточками проблем нет, у гугла имеется удобная API для получения статической картинки из street view.

Проблема следующая:
Необходимо получать каждый раз рандомные координаты на территории Российской Федерации. Друзья, возможно кто то знает какой то сервис для этих целей или может есть какой то лаконичный вариант решения данной проблемы.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можете генерировать абсолютно случайные координаты, а потом просто проверять, что такая точка лежит в РФ.

Comment: это очень накладно, так как необходимо задать координаты всех границ, дабы не уехать в монголию например)

Comment: М, разве в апи нельзя взять адрес у произвольной точки?

Comment: @EzikBro Именно у street view static api - нет, потому что она принимает на вход координаты и по ним возвращает статическую картинку, а другой апихи не нашёл. Если поделишься буду благодарен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ищете полигон Российской Федерации, например в формате `geojson`. А дальше рандомно генерируете координату внутри этого полигона.

Первая попавшиеся ссылка geojson стран: [тык](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json)

Я бы так решил задачу.

Comment: Интересный вариант, спасибо!